# TYPO3 - backend login does not work after upgrade to 9.5.x (RSA authentication)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I upgraded from TYPO3 8.7.31 to 9.5.22. All worked fine and I successfully tested the system.
After the upgrade I recognized a deprecated extension "RSA authentication". I removed the extension. After logout from BE I'm not able to login again.

Comment: via install tool I was able to create a new admin user. With this user we could reactivate the rsa extension .. now it works again :-)
what is a good way to remove rsaauth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set `[BE][loginSecurityLevel]` to `normal` instead of `rsa` in your LocalConfiguration.php? This can be done via the Install Tool as well.

This setting must be changed before your remove EXT:rsauth.

If you have a frontend login, you need to do the same for `[FE][loginSecurityLevel]` as well.

See this document for details: [Deprecation: #81852 - Deprecated Usage of EXT:rsaauth](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.1/Deprecation-81852-DeprecatedUsageOfEXTrsaauth.html)